# adding a background image in flex 4.6

Tags: apache-flex

Doing a Flex 4.6 mobile app I am trying to add an asset .png file to be displayed as the background to the application across all the different views and orientations. Has anyone worked out a way to do this yet?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Tried the container and Skinning methods currently available.  I have also referenced the adobe Docs to no avail.  However I must admit I am not the best at sorting through the Docs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<s:View>
 <fx:Script>
    [Embed(source="myImage.gif")]
    public var myImage :Class;
  </fx:Script>
  <s:Image source="myImage" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</s:View>
```

[Info about Embedding images in Flex](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_4.html)

However, I don't expect perfect results.  A PNG is a pre-rendered bitmap.  Most likely it will not look right across all views and orientations [and resolutions] because elements of the PNG may be skewed, stretched, or compressed, with it is resized on the fly; for example when switching from portrait to landscape.

Answer (score 0):

I've been in this hole and I know the way out.

You'll need to create a skin class for your application. It doesn't have to be too complex here's what my file (appSkin.mxml) looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
<fx:Metadata>
    [HostComponent("spark.components.View")]
</fx:Metadata>

<!-- states -->
<s:states>
    <s:State name="disabled" />
    <s:State name="normal" />
</s:states>

<s:BitmapImage  source="@Embed('assets/bg.png')" width="100%" height="100%" />

<s:Group id="contentGroup" width="100%" height="100%" minWidth="0" minHeight="0" />


<!-- SkinParts
name=contentGroup, type=spark.components.Group, required=false
-->
```

Then you'll need to declare that file as your application's *skinClass* in your application's opening tag…

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" applicationDPI="320"
           creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler()" xmlns:views="views.*" skinClass="skins.appSkin">
```

Then you'll have to do one final step. Each of your View components are carrying an opaque background layer so in each of them you'll want to explicitly set that *backgroundAlpha* value to 0.

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Start" backgroundAlpha="0">
```

And that should accomplish your mission of maintaining a common background image for your application across multiple views.